# listview itemcommand not firing after back button

Tags: asp.net, back-button

I have page that uses a multiview. Each view contains a separate user control. One of these user controls has a list view with an image button that causes the loading of a different view in the multiview. All is fine up until this point. When the user hits the back button, they are taken back to the user control that contains the list view. The user then clicks on another image button to view different data and it returns to the detail user control using the same data as before. While debugging, I have seen that the item command event does not fire after hitting the back button.

I have tried replacing the multiview and putting each user control into separate panels. This did not change the outcome at all.

I have tried setting a cookie that expires 5 seconds after page load. When the user continues to the next page, then clicks back (and it has been longer than 5 seconds), I force the form to submit again. This loads the next control again instead of reloading the page.

I have tried setting the cacheability to no cache. This causes a "page expired" message and the user has to refresh the page. This is ugly for the user and definitely takes away from the user experience.

I am looking for the cleanest way for a user to click back and have the page reloaded so that the item command event fires correctly again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took a lot of research to find this answer, so hopefully other people stumble upon this question and find my answer. I was astonished that I was actually able to find this. Ok, enough gloating.

Because the page does not postback when the user clicks the back button, the events are not fired correctly causing problems with the next page. What has to happen is you need to be able to handle the browser's navigation buttons (i.e. back and forward). To do this you have to set EnableHistory to true within the script manager and handle the Navigate event from the script manager. You can then reload the controls using the information you save in the state object.

I used these articles from Dino Esposito on DotNetSlackers.com as a reference. [Server Side History Management](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/AFirstLookAtASPNETExtensions35HistoryPoints.aspx) and [Client Side History Management](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ajax/clienthistorypointsinaspnet35extensions.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that Back doesn't affect the Page Life Cycle.  It's definitely because the page is cached and cached page doesn't execute on server. You can try this code to get rid of this issue.

> Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
>   Response.Cache.SetNoStore();

Comment: I have tried this, but this forces the user to reload the page instead of having the page do it itself. This process needs to be seamless. The user should not be interrupted. All they need to do is hit back, and have the page reload without them having to do a thing.